# Why does Visual Studio add a slash at the start of an int, when it's converted to char?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Why does Visual Studio add a slash at the start of an int, when it's converted to char?

When I convert `int 0` to `char`, it changes to `\0`. Why? I need char 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\0` is just how Visual Studio shows the character `null` in debug windows.

The `\` is an escape sequence, so `\0` tells you this is the `null` character.

If you want the *character* `0`, you need to use the correct ASCII value for that character - 48.

```
char n = (char)0; // The _null_ character, displayed \0
char z = (char)48; // The character 0
char z2 = '0'; // The character 0, using a character literal
```

Answer (score 1):

To recive char '0' convert `int` 48 to `char` or assign simply by

```
var c = '0';
```

When you convert `int` 0 to `char` you receive ASCII symbol at 0 decimal position, which is null. Char '0' has ASCII value as 48, so converting 48 to char will result in '0' `char`.

Check ASCII symbols and their decimal representation at [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Remember, that anytime you convert `int` to `char`, it takes this ASCII table into account

Answer (score 1):

If you want the char 0, you need to use either a character literal:

```
'0'
```

or, you can use

```
0.ToString()[0]
```

Depending on where the value is coming from.

`\0` is an escape sequence for the character with the ASCII value 0, and this is different from the character for the digit 0.